# Command not found while trying to flash Android Things

Tags: android-things

I'm having trouble installing Android Things on an SD card. The card itself seems fine, it's recognised by my Macbook Pro. I'm using the same command i used for the last pi I set up.

Below is the command and the response I'm getting back.

I'm pretty new to Android Things but this command worked like a charm last time and nothing has changed AFAIK so no idea where to go from here.

```
Jamies-MBP:ic-self-help jampez77$ sudo ~/Downloads/android-things-setup-utility/android-things-setup-utility-macos
Password:
sudo: /Users/jampez77/Downloads/android-things-setup-utility/android-things-setup-utility-macos: command not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error implies that the file you are trying to run (`/Users/jampez77/Downloads/android-things-setup-utility/android-things-setup-utility-macos`) is just not where you've said it is.

Rather than trying to run it from a long path, which introduces more chance of a typo, try running it from the directory e.g.

```
cd ~/Downloads/android-things-setup-utility/
sudo ./android-things-setup-utility-macos
```

Also check that directory is still there and that actual command has the execute bit set.

Comment: This is exactly what the problem was. `android-things-setup-utility` had a space at the end of the folder name. Thanks